# How can I set my jwt as a cookie to prevent having to login on refresh?

Tags: javascript, cookies, jwt, axios, js-cookie

I am attempting to store a JWT as a cookie to prevent my Axios call creating a new one each time and making me login every time the app is refreshed

I think I am on the right path using JS-Cookie and setting the cookie to my JWT provided by the API. However I am still redirected on login every refresh. How can I keep the authToken as my original JWT token?

```
import axiosAPI from 'axios';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

let authToken = null;

const axios = axiosAPI.create({
    baseURL: `${baseURL}`
});


// User login
export const loginUser = (data) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.post(`${baseURL}/jwt-auth/v1/token`, data)
            .then((res) => {
                if (Cookies.get('token') == null) {
                    authToken = res.data.token;
                } else {
                    Cookies.set('token', res.data.token);
                    authToken = Cookies.get('token');
                }

                // Adds the token to the header
                axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${authToken}`;

                resolve(res.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
    });
};
```

I have also tried this:

```
import axiosAPI from 'axios';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const authToken = Cookies.get('token');

const axios = axiosAPI.create({
    baseURL: `${baseURL}`
});

// User login
export const loginUser = (data) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.post(`${baseURL}/jwt-auth/v1/token`, data)
            .then((res) => {
                if (Cookies.get('token') === null) {
                    Cookies.set('token', res.data.token);
                }

                // Adds the token to the header
                axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${authToken}`;

                resolve(res.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
    });
};
```

which fails to log me in altogether

Comment: you dont need to wrap your axios post in a promise it already is a promise

Comment: you need to get the cookie on load and set it as your default header atm i imagine nothing is setting that until after you login